# Outlook Add-In dialog box is too small in Windows desktop client

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

I am currently creating a contextual Add-In for Outlook which opens an additional dialog box when the link is clicked.

On the Web client, the dialog box correctly opens to 80% size of the **browser** window.

However, on the desktop client, the dialog box opens to 80% of the size of the **Add-In** pane window - ie. much smaller.

The dialog box size is set by percentage of display width and height in the following line of code:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myWebPage.html', { height: 80, width: 80, displayInIframe: true });
```

How can I get the size of the dialog box to be relative to the size of the Outlook window rather than the Add-In window on desktop client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this functionality is not part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.